# Can Kubernetes pods that use host networking access Service resources by the service name and service port?

Tags: kubernetes, service, hostnetwork

Can Kubernetes pod that uses the host network send requests directly to a Service resource by using the service name and service port (incl. utilization of CoreDNS)? Or do I have to expose the service via nodePort on the host network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a pod to send requests directly to service resource you have to change pod's `dnsPolicy` to [`ClusterFirstWithHostNet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy). It should be used explicitly for pods running with `hostNetwork: true`. This way it will use cluster DNS and will be in host network.

You can check it in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. When you are using `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst` this file is inherited by pod and uses host's DNS resolver.
When you set `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` it will change DNS resolver to cluster's DNS.